# Change current in steps for pulsed LEDs

Tags: led, mosfet, driver, infrared

I want to control the power consumption and intensity of a IR LED which is fed by a 38kHz signal.
Can I add mosfets in series with different resistors (25/250) like in my schematic? Application is a battery powered beam brake.

IRLML2502PBF MOSFET datasheet [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2502pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668048e2606)

Do I need additional resistor in gate and between gate and source?
Driven by 5V Atmega328P or maybe 3.3V to lower the power consumption.
Also, am I right that using mosfets instead of  bipolar transistors is more energy-saving?

[image]

Version 2
[image: Version 2]

Comment: Place resistors in drain rather than source of FETs. | As shown you get I = V/R = (Vdrive - Vgsth)/R .

Comment: You can get high low medium power this way.  01 10 11 . You could also just send PWM to one or other bottom FET.

Comment: Ok, changed the resistors. low/medium/high is a great idea! PWM doesn't work I guess because of the 38kHz signal. Added a second question

Comment: What input - output expectations do you have ? optical , electrical , control, tolerance, power current voltage . I call these Design Specs.  These are more important than a schematic that doesn't work.

Comment: MOSFET datasheet here https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2502pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668048e2606

Comment: Drive via maybe 10 Ohm resistors. At 38 kHz you may be OK with direct gate drive - a simple gate driver may help square things up but it's not too demanding - probably. You can omit Q-high and just PWM either left or right fet gate for high or low power. | I fet approx ((Vcc - Vled-Vlowerfeton) / R  ~~= (5-2-0.1) / R = 2.9/R =! 115 mA or 12 mA. Maybe a little less.

Comment: tony, sorry I dont know what you mean. I just have a Led taht should flash at 38kHz with two different currents

Comment: PWM either left or right doesnt work for me as I only have one specific pin for creating the 38kHz

Comment: @user3435167 Is this a break-beam IR sensor and you want the IR LED emitter to continually emitting, just at two different settable intensities where the intensities are selected by the LO and HI state of a 38 kHz input signal? If so, is this because you intend on using a possibly crystal-controlled but regardless very narrow-band electronic filter as part of the overall optical/electronic receiver package?

Comment: @jonk yes it is and you're right with two different levels, it's controlled by a mcu. Maybe it's possible to go for a second PWM but therefore I need to make a redesign. Is the solution with only two mosfets more energy saving?

Comment: @user3435167 Efficient in this case says to me "low voltage overhead." (You can't use PWM averaging.) Which means you design the power source to provide almost exactly what you need for the highest current setting and only enough more to provide the control overhead you need. The other component is that you want two currents. So you set up for one which is always present as the base and then add one enabled by either the HI or the LO of your control signal. Do you need precision current levels? Or can it be just different by vague factors?

Comment: @user3435167 For the cartoon version, imagine your emitter in series with resistor R1 across a given voltage supply. Now add another resistor, R2, in parallel to R1 but where R2 is first in series with a switch that is controlled by your 38 kHz. The control frequency simply places R2 in parallel with R1, or not. Thus, the current modulates. That's the cartoon version. So tell me what's wrong with the cartoon.

Comment: it can be vague factors. I need ca 20mA and 200mA. I need to draw your cartoon actually to understand it ;)

Comment: I attached a second version with only one additional mosfet. Is this possible?